# A specific notation for invertible sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading Milne's Jacobian Varieties, where on the discussion after Proposition 2.1 in Chapter 2, he says the following:

> Let $P \in C(k)$, where $C$ is a proper nonsingular curve over $k$ and let $L^P$ be the invertible sheaf
>   $$ L(\Delta - C \times \{P\} - \{P\} \times C)$$ on $C \times C$, where $\Delta$ is the diagonal. Observe that $L^P$ is symmetric and that $L^P \mid C \times \{Q\} \cong L(Q - P)$

First of all, how should I make sense of $\Delta - C \times \{P\} - \{P\} \times C$? It seems to be that by $\Delta$, it means the image of $\Delta: C \to C \times C$, and then the minus signs are set differences. But then the final result is a set, so how should I then interpret $L(-)$? I am only recalling $L(D)$ for some Cartier divisor.

Secondly, by symmetric, what does he mean? I know that if we have a line bundle on an abelian variety, we can define symmetric to be $(-1)^* L \equiv L$, but here we are a priori just working on curves.

Comment: Divisors form a group. He has three (prime) divisors $D_1,D_2,D_3$ and he's forming $D_1-D_2-D_3$.

Comment: I see, so we're interpreting $C \times \{P\}$ as a codimension 1 subvariety, thus a Weil divisor. How about $\Delta$ though?

Comment: $C\times C$ has an obvious involution. Symmetric means invariant under that involution.

Comment: $\Delta$ is also codimension $1$. For the second question: my guess is that he means that if you take the involution of $C\times C$ that swaps the factors then the divisor gets pulled back (or pushed forward, it doesn't matter) to itself. Probably he wants to descend this thing to $\operatorname{Sym^2} C$.

Comment: The diagonal is also a codimension 1 subvariety!